# Why would a synthesized Getter result in a release?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, nsuserdefaults

According to Instruments, my object is sent a `release` message on this line:

`[currentDefaults setObject:self.myArray forKey:@"storedArray"]`

This is causing over-release and crash. NSZombies when Profiled found this line and the retain count issue.

But why? The synthesized property is this:

`@property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray*myArray;`

Why is the line at the top causing the retain count to change?

Here is the backtrace after crash (the line 103 mentioned is the line above):

```
(lldb) bt
* thread #20: tid = 0x3103, 0x01e31276 CoreFoundation`CFRetain + 22, stop reason =     EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_I386_BPT, subcode=0x0)
frame #0: 0x01e31276 CoreFoundation`CFRetain + 22
frame #1: 0x01eeca00 CoreFoundation`__CFDictionaryStandardRetainValue + 80
frame #2: 0x01e74e62 CoreFoundation`__CFBasicHashReplaceValue + 34
frame #3: 0x01e41964 CoreFoundation`CFBasicHashSetValue + 2628
frame #4: 0x01e40ee3 CoreFoundation`CFDictionarySetValue + 227
frame #5: 0x01e773b5 CoreFoundation`-[CFXPreferencesSource setValue:forKey:] + 85
frame #6: 0x01e8a81e CoreFoundation`-[CFXPreferencesPropertyListSource setValue:forKey:] + 110
frame #7: 0x01e8a72f CoreFoundation`_CFXPreferencesSetValue + 159
frame #8: 0x01e8a5b3 CoreFoundation`CFPreferencesSetAppValue + 51
frame #9: 0x01372ceb Foundation`-[NSUserDefaults(NSUserDefaults) setObject:forKey:] + 100
frame #10: 0x00003922 Ivory Bull Charts`__21-[SavedData saveData]_block_invoke_0 + 178 at SavedData.m:103
frame #11: 0x017a3330 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_call_block_and_release + 15
frame #12: 0x017a4439 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_worker_thread2 + 302
frame #13: 0x996a3b24 libsystem_c.dylib`_pthread_wqthread + 346
(lldb)
```

Comment: `myArray` is getting the extra `release` message?

Comment: Post the backtrace of the release.

Comment: yes `myArray` is the object in question

Comment: Do your objects in myArray conform NSCopying protocol?

Comment: the objects are all standard collection classes, does that answer the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a copy of your arrays or dictionaries and store those in user defaults, rather than the instance variables themselves and see if it prevents retain issues when you re-store the same variable contents to the user defaults.

Answer (score 3):

Frankly, just guessing.

In your backtrace there is "CFBasicHashReplaceValue". My guess is that your are not just adding an object with a new key but replacing an existing object that uses the same key within this dictionary.

That existing object would be removed from the dictionary and released. That existing object may have been over-released before this happens.

Comment: It is true that I am replacing an object in userDefaults, which I thought is acceptable by doing the above. Is it not? But your point raises another point: does userDefaults create a new copy of the object you store in it, or does it actually reference your live active object?

Comment: I will not sign this in blood: AFAIK there is no copy created but the original object retained when adding to the dictionary and released when removing from it. Frankly I donnot know what userDefauls does. You should have a closer look on the current retain count of the very object that you are going to remove (by replacing) from the dictionary. It should be 1 (at least - even ore if you continue using it) before adding the new object using the same key.

Comment: Before continuing down this line of investigation - check out this handy website RE retainCount [whentouseretaincount.com/](http://whentouseretaincount.com/)